# how to resolve "LLVM ERROR: Tried to execute an unknown external function"

Tags: compiler-construction, clang, llvm, llvm-ir

I am writing a pass that puts instructions into LLVM IR that are defined in an archive and should then be called from the IR during execution. I need to use the lli interpreter for this. the command I use is:

---

lli-8 -extra-archive="/build/rtlib/mylib.a" -force-interpreter input.ll

---

the IR where I am calling my library:

```
define protected i32 @main(i32, i8**) #0 !dbg !28 {
entry:
  call void @func_entry(i32 16385, i32 1)
.
.
.
declare void @func_entry(i32, i32)
```

LLVM ERROR: Tried to execute an unknown external function which is declared at the bottom of the IR file.

Answer (score 0):

If the .a is an archive of LLVM-IR, then use llvm-link or llvm-ld to link them with your input and run that in the interpreter.

Otherwise LLI with interpreter will attempt to use FFI to call external functions. Is your `lli-8` built with FFI enabled? Does the .a file define a symbol with exactly the name "func_entry" and not "_Zfunc_entry" or "_func_entry"? You can check the symbols defined in your `.a` file with `nm` or `llvm-nm`.